# How can I stop my object from mirroring across the y axis?

Tags: modeling, mirror

Video: https://youtu.be/XsGMN7Ua3cM

The sphere is mirroring across the y axis. As you can see, I have a mirror modifier, but that is along the x, not y axis.

This doesn't happen for the part at the bottom, by the way. Only the circle at the top.

Comment: Please add the images. It seems that you are referring to images that you think you have attached, but actually accidentally didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the effect of the *Mirror* modifier that you show but the effect of the Y symmetry option, just disable it:

[image]